# Making a JDialog button respond to the Enter key

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have a JQueryDialog with a text field, an OK button and a cancel button.

I want to be able to hit the enter key after filling in the text fields and have it do the same action as when I click the OK button.

Comment: Are JQueryDialog(in question) and JDialog(in title) surely the same things?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your dialog, call `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is almost correct. I would change the if comparison and use the correct method as noted below.

```
if (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER == event.getKeyCode()) {
                yourButton.doClick();
            }
```

Comment: It looks like the original code that I responded to is missing.